# Accessing GridView's ViewState

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, dataview

**What I have:**

I have a GridView without paging. In the Page_Load handler of the containing Page I read user specific values from a table storage and store them in a collection so the SelectMethod of the ObjectDataSource can get them.

**What I want:**

When the user uploads some new data from the same page the GridView is in I want the GridView to show the new data additionally to the old one without querying the storage again.

**Helpful stuff:**

IsPostback within the Page_Load handler helps avoiding queries when the data is still in the ViewState. After the user clicked the upload button he can still see the old data thanks to the ViewState of the GridView I guess.

**My attempt:**

I tried to derive from GridView and make my own user control in order to have access to the ViewState Property that returns a StateBag but it cannot find the user data that is displayed in it. It shows only stuff like DataSourceID, _!ItemCount and so on.

**My Question:**

How to access ViewState from a GridView in order to retrieve data like the column values or the DataKeyName values from code behind.

**Additional info:**

The answer to the question [does gridview save data in viewstate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503525/does-gridview-save-data-in-viewstate) states that the GridView saves its data in its ViewState.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to access the GridView's view state. That's an internal implementation detail of the control and could change at any time.

All you need to do is call `DataBind()` on the GridView after you set the new data and the control will show the updated data.

Comment: @user764754 Can you post some of what you've done?  But it does sound like you just need to bind it again.

Comment: If I only set the new data the GridView will show nothing else. The old data from the ViewState is lost if I DataBind the new data. Since I don't want to make a new query when PostBack occurs I only have the new data in code behind and the old is somewhere hidden in the ViewState of the GridView (from the initial Page_Load). I'll post the code tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: You're probably right with not accessing the ViewState of the GridView. My solution now is to store the queried data in the page ViewState myself. This ViewState is used to get the old data during PostBacks. Old data is modified then DataBind() gets called and the page's ViewState is updated accordingly. I also set EnableViewState="False" on the GridView to avoid storing my data in the page's ViewState and in the GridView's ViewState. This workaround works. I don't think I have to post my old code now ;)