# Asp.net saving a view

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I save a view in asp.net with a gridview. Right now I have it like this:

```
com = new SqlCommand("select o.ordernr,o.loginnr,k.voornaam,k.achternaam,k.woonplaats,k.postcode,k.telefoonnr,"+
            "s.klantstatus,o.klantbericht from ordergegevens o inner join status s on o.klantstatus=s.id inner join klantgegevens k on k.klantid=o.loginnr",conn);

     SqlConnection conn = sqlConn.sqlConnect();
            conn.Open();
            scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
            saved = sda.Update(dt);
            if (saved != 0)
            {
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "saved");
            }
            else
            {
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Now changes to save");
            }
            conn.Close();save
```

This will give the error:

> > An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Dynamic SQL generation is not supported
>   against multiple base tables.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataTable table = GetTable();

GridView1.DataSource = table;

GridView1.DataBind();

ViewState["myState"] = GridView1.DataSource;
```

I believe I'm reading the question correctly. Doing the following allows you to save the gridview into a viewstate.

You may find relevant information at [This Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503525/does-gridview-save-data-in-viewstate).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm going to try that.